# What is a JavaScript Blob object, why is it useful?

Tags: javascript

I recently ran into the JavaScript Blob object, I used it to initialize a web worker where the code was contained within a script tag in the document.

Based on the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) documentation:

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format.

It sounds like it acts as a sack to put a collection of things into that all share a MIME type. Am I wrong in this opinion, is this opinion incomplete?

Why is the object needed/useful?

Comment: it's simply a better binary string than String(). a bytearray. no unicode coercion. you can use it to store a mp3 or jpg that won't store correctly in a normal js string. you use FileReader() or URL.createObjectURL() to read the contents, or in web workers, FileReaderSync.

Comment: @dandavis Well it is most definitely making sense now thanks.

Answer (score 20):

`Blob`s aren't terribly useful on their own. What's useful about them is that they work with many calls which are meant to process `File`s. The most important of these is [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), which can be used to create a URL you can then use in the `href` or `src` attributes of HTML tags, [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) statements and [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) values in CSS, etc.

Basically, `Blob` gives JavaScript something like temporary files, and `URL.createObjectURL()` lets you treat those blobs as though they were files on a web server.

Answer (score 12):

You may need to send through an API where a URL is expecting data that is file-like.

> Blobs allow you to construct file like objects on the client that you can pass to apis that expect urls instead of requiring the server provides the file.

See more [here](http://www.javascripture.com/Blob).

Comment: Well that certainly fits the description of how I used it.

Comment: Blobs on their own are not file-like as seen from remote URLs, you would need to use FormData to convert them first. Blobs themselves also provide no URL, though you can make one from a Blob with FileReader or URL.createObjectURL, and you can get them from ajax via xhr.responseType='blob', so while your answer hints around different potential aspects of blobs, it doesn't provide a lot of info to go on.

Comment: Also a nice way to mock api calls