# What is blob:http://localhost:9000/064e8460-0ef0-4903-a867-7548088308a3 in ace.js

Tags: ace-editor

In my application which uses `ace.js`, it seems that `ace` tries to get files from server by code which looks like `blob:http://localhost:9000/064e8460-0ef0-4903-a867-7548088308a3`. This maps to code like `importScripts('http://localhost:9000/ace-builds/worker-html.js');`.

What is `ace` trying to do here? My unit tests randomly fail because server returns `404` for request `blob:http://localhost:9000/064e8460-0ef0-4903-a867-7548088308a3`.

What is happening under the hood? I would like to try to resolve the issue?

Comment: [General answer as to what blob is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055587/what-is-a-javascript-blob-object-why-is-it-useful), but not an answer for what ace.js is doing (I'm not familiar with that lbirary - sorry).

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a new question. Is it something you can look at as well please -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813206/do-i-need-to-set-content-security-policy-when-running-jasmine-karma-test-cases